# Rational-radii circles packed along the x-axis

Tags: real-numbers, infinity, rational-numbers, osculating-circle

> ***Q0***. Can all rationals in $(0,1)$ be realized at $x$-coordinates of tangent circles in the arrangement below?

I think the answer to ***Q0*** is *Yes*.

---

[image: KissingCircles]

          

<sup>Rationals up to depth $16$.</sup>

---

> ***Q1***. What is the ratio of the area covered by the disks
>   touching the $x$-axis in $(0,1)$, and the triangular region between
>   the $x=0$ and $x=1$ circles and the $x$-axis?

Far-fetched:

> ***Q2***. Is there any way to use this example to show intuitively
>   that the cardinality of the reals exceeds the cardinality of the rationals.

I think the answer to ***Q2*** is *No*.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford_circle

Comment: Are these *Ford circles*?

Comment: Joseph, I just ordered Weissman's new book, te Ford circles are one arrangement diagram for $PSL_2 \mathbb Z$ One area is Pell type equations and Conway's topograph, http://bookstore.ams.org/mbk-105/

Comment: Thanks, @WillJagy & LSUnknown. I did not know the Ford terminology.  My real interest is in ***Q2***.

Comment: [This](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjM2deDiO7VAhVBHGMKHdk3DgEQygQILTAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FFord_circle%23Total_area_of_Ford_circles&usg=AFQjCNHywxFcrFFMCvyYGdPU22EhDL_tJg) might help with Q2

Comment: @V.Chen: Thanks!  Very neat that $\zeta(3)$ is a factor in the expression for the area.